# 3D scatter plot with 4D data

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, colormap

I need to plot a 3D figure with each data point colored with the value of a 4th variable using a colormap. Lets say I have 4 variables X,Y,Z and W where W = f(X,Y,Z). I want a 3D plot with X, Y, and Z as the three axis. The statement `scatter3(X,Y,Z,'filled','b')` gives me a scatter plot in 3D but I want to incorporate the value of Z in the graph by representing the points as an extra parameter (either with different areas :bigger circles for data points with high value of Z and small circles for data points with low value of Z or by plotting the data points with different colors using a colormap). However, I am a novice in MATLAB and dont really know how to proceed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your statement `scatter3(X,Y,Z,'filled','b')`, the `'b'` represent the color blue. Since you specify only one color, it is applied to all the points. If you use `scatter3(X,Y,Z,'filled',W)`, the markers should have a different color (relative to your 4th axis W). Also note that you could replace the `'filled'` parameter by a vector of numeric value (same length as the others) which would control the size of each marker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So just use `z` for the size vector (4th input) as well as the color vector (5th input):

```
z = 10*(1:pi/50:10*pi);
y = z.*sin(z/10);
x = z.*cos(z/10);

figure(1)
scatter3(x,y,z,z,z)

view(45,10)
colorbar
```

The size vector needs to be greater 0, so you may need to adjust your `z` accordingly.

[image]

Comment: too bad, 30sec and i dont have an image ;)

Comment: Can i color the surface based on the categories in a data. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981257/color-3d-surface-based-on-categories-that-passes-through-scatter-points

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Please post a new one with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are already nearly there... simply use

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,s,W);
```

where s is the point size (scalar, e.g. 3) and W is a vector with your W values.
You might also want to issue an

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer','OpenGL');
```

where gcf gets your current figure you are plotting in to significantly increase responsiveness when scattering a lot of data.