# Scatter plot with different size for each point

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot

I have several thousands of points to plot (about 10k) and I would like to plot them with Matlab but deciding a diferent size for each of the points (and a different color if possible). I tried to make a scatter plot for each point, but it is extremely slow compared to a single scatter call for all the points. Is there a way to plot several points in Matlab with different properties for each point, that works in a reasonable amount of time?

In case it is not possible to do it with Matlab, is there a way to do it with gnuplot?

Comment: Just for the reference, the [**3D case**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816470/3d-scatter-plot-with-4d-data/25816666#25816666) of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`scatter(x, y, a, c)`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) takes arguments `x` and `y`, and then `a` for size, and `c` for colour. `a` can either be a single scalar, or a vector with a size for each `(x,y)` point. `c` can be an [RGB triplet](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html), or a vector, the same size as `x` and `y`. For example:

```
x = 1:4;
scatter(x, x, 10*x, x);
```

results in

[image: Example]

So in your case, perhaps

```
scatter(xData, yData, [], 1:10000)
```

will result in your data having a different colour determined by its position in the data array.

Comment: Nice example! Better than the one based on random values that I was preparing :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, only thing I was tempted to change with it is the colour of the last point a bit hard to see.

Answer (score 3):

For gnuplot it's easy, suppose you write your datafile with 3 columns, all you have to do is

```
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3:3 with circles lc palette
```

[HERE](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/circles.html) you can find some examples (for help type `help circles`).

If you want just what is called **variable pointsize** (pointsize is not related to the real axis) you can use:

```
plot 'data.dat' with points ps variable pt 7
```

[HERE](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pointsize.html) you can find some examples (for help type `help pointsize`).

Answer (score 2):

For gnuplot you can combine `pointsize variable` and `linecolor variable` or `linecolor palette`:

```
set xrange [0:10]
set samples 21
plot '+' using 1:1:(0.2*$1):1 with point pointsize variable linecolor palette pt 7 notitle
```

[image]